# How to remove 'file ownership' in explorer, win 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I want to remove 'File ownership' from every folder in the red circle, so I uncheck it, but it appears again when I reopen explorer.

[image: figure, not have enough reputation to show it directly]

Answer (score 0):

There are two options you can do here.

1. Reset the views of all folders to their default
2. Set a new standard view and then apply that view to all folders.

If you go for option 2, do note that from now on, all folders will appear the same. If you want a per folder view, you will have to reset the view to the defaults and then make changes for each folder. When setting a new standard view for all folders, it will continue to override views, as what is happening to you right now, until new changes are reapplied.

Lets assume you go for option 2, set the desired view and columns in an explorer window of your choice. Once that is done, from the ribbon menu, go to `View` > `Options` > `View`.

At the top, there are 2 buttons.
<kbd>Apply to Folders</kbd> and <kbd>Reset Folders</kbd>.

The first button is for situation 2 where the 2nd button is for situation 1. As I assumed you would want to set the new view, press the <kbd>Apply to Folders</kbd> button.

Press <kbd>OK</kbd> to exit the window, and that's basically it. From now on, every explorer window will have these settings.

If you opted to reset the folders instead, the same applies, except from now on all folders will have their default view. This view can be different for folders such as My Documents and My Pictures compared to other folders.

When individual folder settings are changed and there is no overruling policy in effect, each folder will have a hidden desktop.ini which has the configuration stored for that folder. But as mentioned earlier, that file is ignored if an "Apply to all folders" policy is in effect, which is set if you choose the "Apply to Folders" option.

Comment: I take a try and it remains there when I reopen explorer, is there a way using registry     to make it?

Comment: No, this is not stored in the registry, but if it only happens to that folder, Enable Show hidden files and disable hide protected system files in the settings of Explorer (that view > options menu) then you should see that desktop.ini file I mentioned earlier. Remove it, navigate out of the folder and navigate back into it to ensure that it worked. Closing exlorer and reopening it would now remember the setting. Alternatively, you can also use a command prompt window to delete that desktop.ini file. use `attrib +a -h -s desktop.ini` in that folder to make it visible.

Comment: It happens to all of my folders. In fact, I uncheck 'file ownership' in folder A, it do disappear,(choose Apply to Folders, or not), then I navigate to folder B, the 'file ownership' remains, and I navigate back to folder A, the 'file ownership' appears again. I even need not close&reopen explorer.

Comment: So there is a desktop.ini file that sets it.